# python - updated dictionary with same key value pair

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've seem to hit a wall with dictionaries in python.
Is it possible to update a dictionary with the same key value pair.
Whenever I try to update my dictionary with the same key value pair, the update action is not performed, it sort of ignores the pair to update because of duplication.  Is there some limitation to updating key value pair duplicates in a python dictionary?

I have posted my code below for demonstration.
Thanks Inadvance.

```
import time
import collections
from random import randrange


def faceCard(card,cardNum):
    cDict = collections.OrderedDict()
    print("Card:",card)
    if card == 11:
        cDict["Jack"] = 10
    elif card == 12:
        cDict["Queen"] = 10
    elif card == 13:
        cDict["King"] = 10
    elif card == 14:
        cDict["Ace"] = 11
    else:
        cDict[cardNum] = card

    return cDict

def main():
    pCards = collections.OrderedDict()
    dCards = collections.OrderedDict()

    while True:
        pCards.update(faceCard(randrange(2,15,1),"pCard1"))
        time.sleep(.25)
        dCards.update(faceCard(randrange(2,15,1),"dCard1"))
        time.sleep(.25)
        pCards.update(faceCard(randrange(2,15,1),"pCard2"))
        time.sleep(.25)
        dCards.update(faceCard(randrange(2,15,1),"dCard2"))
        time.sleep(.25)

        print("Player",pCards)
        print("Dealer",dCards)

        pCards.clear()
        dCards.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected behavior? Where does it happen? What have you already tried?

Comment: Since dictionaries are "an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique" what would the purpose of trying to add a duplicate?

Comment: When I run the program and try to add an exact key value pair that already exist in a dictionary, the update does not add it in.  
For example the second and fourth pairs will be identical, please see results below:

('Card:', 9)

('Card:', 11)

('Card:', 14)

('Card:', 11)

('Player', {'pCard1': 9, 'Ace': 11})

('Dealer', {'Jack': 10})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what a dictionary does.

A key may appear only once in the dictionary.  It has one value associated with it, whatever the most recent assignment was.

Think of it like a telephone book: you keep the name of each person in only a single entry, associated with **one** phone number.  If you overwrite with a name and the same phone number, you see no change.  If you overwrite with a new phone number, that supersedes out the old one.  (Yes, you could maintain a list of telephone numbers for one person, but that's an extension of this example).

Comment: So I cannot have multiple indices with the same key value pair?
For example: ('Player', {'Queen': 10, 'Queen': 10})

Thanks InAdvance

Comment: Right -- this is simply not possible with a dictionary.  The one you list has only one entry.  What are you trying to represent?  All the pieces on the board and their values?  That sounds like a list of tuples.

Comment: In learning python, I created a program that simulates a blackjack casino game. So when the each player receives two cards.  Sometimes a player will receive a pair of Jacks, or Queens, etc.  When this happens, I use the .update function add the key,value pair.  If it already exist in the dictionary, the new key,value pair seems to be ignored or is simply overwritten.

Comment: I see.  Why are you using a dictionary?  A simple list of cards is the usual way to represent a hand.  If there's something wonderful you're doing with a dictionary, you'll have to pick a unique key, such as {"Queen of hearts": 10, "Queen of clubs": 10}

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for.  The key has to be unique.
Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple values associated with a key, you could store it as a dictionary of `<key, <list_of_values>>`.

```
cDict = {}

def insert_into_dict(val):
    if key not in cDict:
        cDict[key] = [val]
    else:
        cDict[key].append(val)
```